# Where do I palce the "ng-app" directive in ASP.net MVC application for each pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

If we use a master layout page in `MVC` application normally we add  tag to layout page. So we can add "`ng-app`" directive to that body tag.
So that will be common for the `MVC` application
But what should I do if I want a separate "`ng-app`" directive for each view page in `MVC` application ??

Comment: You will have to individual inject the ng-app attribute for each of the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to put the controller name and action into the ViewData so I can add a CSS class to the body tag:

```
        ViewData["controller"] = RouteData.Values["controller"].NullSafeToString().ToLower();
        ViewData["action"] = RouteData.Values["action"].NullSafeToString().ToLower();
```

then

```
<body class="@controller-@action">
```

you could use this method to create a ng-app attribute instead

OR

the ng-app doesn't have to be on the body tag. it just has to be on a tag that wraps all angular activity. it could applied to the first DIV in each view, instead of in the master layout.

Comment: Thank you. You clarify my doubt with this  "it could applied to the first DIV in each view, instead of in the master layout."